# Do small Calculation Task in Background Using RxJava in Most Efficient Way

Tags: android, performance, rx-java, reactive

How to do simple calculation or small operation in background thread using RxJava in Most Efficient way.

Ps. Efficiency in terms of lesser and compact code.

Comment: Asking for "most efficient" is an open-ended request for opinions, frowned upon in this forum. You need to provide some code so we have context to answer at least part of your question. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use RxJava you get to leverage non-blocking by composing multiple operations in Observables. There are plenty of tutorials out there to help. To answer your question though using RxJava 1:

```
Completable
    .fromRunnable(() -> doSomething())
    .doOnError(e -> log.error(e.getMessage(), e))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe();
```

If `doSomething` doesn't use CPU exclusively then you might choose `Schedulers.io()` instead of `Schedulers.computation()`.